# Performant way to check if a point is in a list of points

Tags: python, numpy

Given a 2D numpy array containing a number of points:

```py
import numpy as np

points = np.array([
    [0, 2],
    [1, 3],
    [2, 3],
    [2, 5],
    [3, 4],
    [3, 5],
    [3, 7],
    [4, 7],
    [4, 8],
    [5, 6],
    [5, 9],
    [6, 7],
    [6, 9],
    [7, 8],
    [7, 9],
])
```

What is most performant way to check if a given point (e.g. `[6,8]`) is in the array?

For example:

```py
y = []
for i in points:
    y.append(np.array_equal([6, 8], i))

True in y
```

yields `False`, as expected.

---

`np.isin([6,8], points)` is unacceptable, as it checks the columns independently, yielding `array([ True,  True])`.

Comment: Why must it be a Numpy array? Can't you use a set of tuples?

Comment: @AKX In my implementation, the points are a slice of a larger array, so Numpy is much preferred. Of course, a tuple-based answer would still be helpful.